# Swift передать данные о нажатом cell в prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, label, uicollectionview, uiviewcontroller

есть стандартная функция, которая должна передать данные ячейки другому UIViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var destinationVC: InformationViewController = segue.destination as! InformationViewController
        //destinationVC.textOfLabel =
    }
```

Ячейка состоит из label и именно ее данные хочу передать в переменную textOfLabel. Останавливаюсь точкой остановки и вижу, что в sender есть данные label, но я не знаю как их получить и как к ним обратиться, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать!
Спасибо!

[image: Скрин точки остановки в функции prepare]

Comment: destinationVC.textOfLabel.text = self.textOfLabel.text

Comment: хотелось бы именно из sender вытащить значение label. Может быть данные для передачи на другую view как то по другому берутся? Спасибо!

Comment: а что именно у вас приходит в `sender`?

Comment: Надо sender скастовать до нужного типа вместо Any и можно вытаскивать значение label.

Comment: @schmidt9, label и view

Comment: @DenisCern. вам выше уже сказали что сделать

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, можете пожалуйста подсказать, как именно нужно скастовать sender?

Comment: @schmidt9, спасибо, вижу! Сейчас буду искать информацию как это реализовать

Comment: Реализуется через кастинг с помощью `as`,  как у вас в примере, главное знать структуру сендера

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, используйте в качестве примера вторую строчку из вашего кода.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так:
`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var destinationVC: InformationViewController = segue.destination as! InformationViewController
        let infFromLabel = sender as! UILabel?
        destinationVC.textOfLabel = infFromLabel?.text ?? ""
    }`
Но все равно не может получить значение. Пишет, что не может скастовать в нужное значение.

Comment: Значит, sender это не UILabel. Какой элемент экрана вызывает функцию prepare? Тот и sender.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, тут получаеться при нажатии на ячейку(cell) вызывается функция prepare и это все происходит в CollectionViewController. Ячейка формируется в CollectionViewCell. То есть при нажатии на ячейку sender и является данной ячейкой?

Comment: @DenisCern. остановите дебаггер внутри `prepare` и приложите скрин с тем, что содержится в `sender`

Comment: @schmidt9, сейчас приложу скрин. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если бы распечатали в консоли описание `sender`, то увидели бы примерно следующее

```
Printing description of sender:
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : <SegueTest.CollectionViewCell: 0x7f9325609920; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 41 20.3333); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003c51fa0>>
```

Здесь как раз и указан тип, к которому нужно приводить, чтобы получить доступ к лейблу (здесь класс ячейки у меня называется `CollectionViewCell`)

Соответственно делаем так

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let text = (sender as! CollectionViewCell).label.text
}
```

Comment: Понял! Большое спасибо! Все работает!